# How to implement Google AdMobs banner ad in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, banner

I want to add an banner advertisement in my tabbed app but I am not able to do it.
How exactly can I implement banner adds?
This is what I have tried-

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var banner : GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadBanner()
}

func loadBanner(){
    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    banner.adUnitID = "my_app_id"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    let req : GADRequest = GADRequest()
    banner.loadRequest(req)
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - banner.frame.size.height, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(banner)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the Admob Integration you have to specify testDevices in the GADRequest object like this:

```
var request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];
```

In the testDevices array you can put also the UUIDs of the phones you are testing on.

Also, did you do the steps from [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165)? They are different things.

You should make the following call in didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsMethod:

```
GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID("YOUR_APPLICATION_ID");
```

Don't mistake the APPLICATION_ID with AD_UNIT_ID!